# Detecting Clicks

Tags: java, click, detection

I am trying to increment `clicks` whenever the left mouse button is pressed and released. If it'll help, I am doing this for a very simple mod that I am coding for Minecraft 1.8 that displays your clicking speed. I already have the display done, now I need to calculate the average clicking speed and have that displayed.

This is all I have so far:

```js
package kaelinatorclickingspeedmod;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Mod implements MouseListener {
private static InGameGUI 
inGameGUI = new InGameGUI();
public static InGameGUI getInGameGUI() {
 return inGameGUI;
}
int clicks=0;
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
    clicks++;
  }
}
```

If you want to work out the average number of clicks, you can work out the time elapsed by adding at the start of your program:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then do:

```
long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

to get the time since the program started. You should be able to work out the average number of clicks from there :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a global variable clicks, initialize it to 0, and use clicks++; inside the mouseClicked function. Also make a timer ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html ) that repeats each second, prints the value of clicks on your display and resets clicks to 0.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //display clicks
    clicks=0;
}
Timer clickSpeed=new Timer(1000,this);
clickSpeed.start();
```